# What's the easiest way to increment an ID in HAML?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, haml

```
    -@things.each do |thing|
      %div.thing
        = thing
```

I've seen a few different techniques.  But with the above HAML template, I want each `thing` to have a unique id from 1 to *n+1* things.  What's the best way to dynamically increment the id for all individual `things`?

Ex: For *n* things, I'd like the HTML to look like this.

```
<div class='thing' id='1'>
<div class='thing' id='2'>
...
<div class='thing' id=n+1>
```

Comment: IDs cannot start with an integer, it's invalid.

Comment: you can however have the incrementing id number at the end, just give it an id starting with for instance `thing` then you can do `thing1` `thing2` `thing3` etc

Comment: @PatrickEvans that'd work.  But you're sure about the IDs thing?  I'm loading up a page to test it out now and this works fine <div class="thing" id="1">

Comment: @KeithJohnson see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html) about acceptable id's.

Comment: @PatrickEvans  Good link thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-@things.each_with_index do |thing,index|
  %div.thing{:id => "thing#{index}"}
    = thing
```

Comment: Yeah whoever downvoted needs to explain. I see nothing wrong with this solution.

Answer (score 1):

Something like [dom_id](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/RecordIdentifier/dom_id) might help you in generating unique IDs for HTML elements. It will also fix the problem of starting with a number.